# How to save preferences composed of 2 strings and display them?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I am currently creating an android application. This application should allow users to enter a RSS feed URL and save it as a preference. I know how to save basic preferences (Strings, booleans...) using a key/value attributes. My problem here is I want to save as one preference the URL of the RSS feed and the name of the website (e.g http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss --> CNN top stories).
So in this case a single preference is composed with 2 strings and I don't know how to do that.

I found a JSON module making possible to save objects as preferences but I would like to avoid using any modules for this app.

Is it possible to do what I want without external modules and if yes, could you please help me with this issue ?

Comment: Why has it to be one preference key? You could use two.

Comment: Because it would be a lot of preference key. If I want to remember 10 RSS feeds, I would have 20 keys. But if I want to increase this number there will be too many keys. I thought it would be better to have 1 key for 1 feed.

Comment: If it's too many, use a SQLite database to store them.

Comment: Yes sure, I can do that. I'll see if I can find another solution with the preferences but if not, I'll use a SQLite database. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you are overthinking this. Instead, consider this approach:

```
String rssUrl = "someUrlHere";

String rssWebsite = "Some website name here";

//Now, you can use a delimiter before storing your two values 

String rssUrlAndWebsite = rssUrl + "," + rssWebsite;

//Now you can store this using one key. 

//When you want to read them out, you can use your key to get the value and simply split using the delimiter and there, you will have two values!
```

I hope this helps;

Alternatively, you could store the two values in a table!

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about that before ! Thanks a lot. So there are no natives android mechanisms allowing several string to be store as one preference ?

Comment: I have not seen one such but I will dig into it a little more; I guess it is the TYPE you want to store!

Comment: I don't know what the TYPE is and I didn't really understood the android documentation about it. So maybe I want to store the TYPE ^^

Comment: What I meant was that whatever you store has to be of a certain type like boolean, String, integer etc; Give me a moment to search something

Comment: I have  found this doc here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html you can look at the getStringSet()

Comment: I saw this doc too before. But now I think about it combining the getStringSet() and the solution you gave me above (splitting the URL and the name with a comma) should solve my problem

Comment: Good luck and happy coding. If this will solve your issue, please don't forget to accept this as the answer!